# How can I prove that countable additivity implies continuity in zero?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

So, I am trying to clear up my hand-written notes (and create a clear summary in LaTeX) from my probability theory course, and I am stuck. It's possible that I've wrote something incorrectly, but at least one more person has the same written in his notes.

So. The topic is "Theorem (continuity of probability measure)" (I don't know if that's the proper English name; I am not from an English-speaking country). I am stuck here:

"Let P be some finitely additive function defined on a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$; $P: \mathcal{F} \to [0, 1], P(\Omega) = 1$. Then these properties are equivalent:

1) countable additivity;

2) continuity in zero; that is, $\forall (A_n, n \in \mathbb{N}), A_n \in \mathcal{F}, A_n \downarrow \varnothing;\ A_n \supset A_{n+1} \supset \ldots \text{and} \bigcap\limits_{n}A_n = \varnothing$ implies P(A_n) \to 0".

This was character-by-character transcript of my notes.. Could it be that the mistake is in the definition and I am trying to prove something that is false?

The proof I have is as follows:

"
(1) $\implies$ (2):

Let {A_n} be a family of sets such that $A_n \supset A_{n+1} \supset \ldots$ and $A_n \downarrow \varnothing.$ Let $B_n$ be defined as $A_n \setminus A_{n+1}$. Then $A_k = \bigsqcup\limits_{n=k}^{\infty}B_n$.

It is clear that $A_k \supset \bigsqcup\limits_{n=k}^{\infty}B_n$; let there exist $\omega \in A_k$ such that $\omega \not\in\bigsqcup\limits_{n=k}^{\infty}B_n$. Then it is trivial to show that $\omega\in A_m \forall m>k$; therefore, $\omega \in \bigcap A_n$. CONTRADICTION.
"

I can't see the contradiction! I've spent maybe 2-3 hours reading up on this subject and to no effect! Where could I (professor?) be wrong? What is that crucial last puzzle piece that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

The contradiction is in the fact that there can't be an $\omega \in \cap A_n$, since $\cap A_n = \emptyset$

Comment: But how does $\cap A_n = \emptyset$ come from the fact that P is countably additive?

Comment: @Akiiino: It doesn’t: it’s part of the hypothesis in (2). You’re assuming that hypothesis and (1) and trying to prove that $P(A_n)\to 0$.

Comment: Soo... If we started with (1) and found a contradiction with (2)... doesn't that mean that we disproved (2)...?

Comment: No because $(2)$ is formally a statement $(A)\implies(B)$. So to show $(1) \implies (2)$, we assume $(1)$ and $(A)$ and we want to prove $(B)$. But to do that we need in intermediary result : $A_k \supset \bigsqcup\limits_{n=k}^{\infty}B_n$, which we call $(C)$. This is the thing that we prove by contradiction. We assume $(C)$ is false, that is the "let there exist" part, and we show contradiction with one of our earlier assumptions, here $(A)$. So we have proven $(C)$ and can now keep on with our proof of $(B)$.

Comment: @justt Oh! I think I get it! I'll be back in probably around 15 minutes --- if I manage to write it down and fully understand, I'll accept your answer